# Sharing a variable between COM objects across different applications

Tags: winapi, static, com, ipc, interprocess

I'm implementing a COM shell-extension interface that may be instantiated by different applications.  For example, File Explorer might call it during folder navigation, and then my own application might directly call it from an .exe.  I was hoping to share some simple and temporary state information across all instances of the interface (perhaps just a string or a vector of strings).  I was hoping it would be like a static member variable, except accessible across all applications.

So I was wondering if this is possible, and if so, how to go about doing it. I've been reading about Windows inter-process communications, and it seems like having simple clipboard functionality might suffice, such that each instance could read or write information to a known memory location. But I wouldn't want to use the clipboard specifically, since that's supposed to be called by the user, and I wouldn't want to interfere with the standard copy-and-paste.  Also, I'd like to avoid writing to a file because I think that would slow things down too much.  Is there another type of IPC that's suited to sharing a variable across all COM instances?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a lot of options -- a COM out-of-process server (which is what I would probably use), shared memory, files, databases...

Comment: I think making an out-of-process server might be beyond my skill set, but is this what you mean by shared memory? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory?  If not, is there some other approach to shared memory?  And what do you think is the fastest?

Comment: Or if it's just small data, perhaps pipes suffice?

Comment: @amt528 yes, a named memory mapped view backed by the system paging file will suffice

Comment: Which method, if any, can allow storing an object like a vector?

Comment: Shared memory is the fastest IPC (Interprocess Communication) method, it is for other processes. If you want to store an object like a vector, you just organize the data structures.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by organize?  Do you have to serialize them?

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods to choose. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications). You can try to implement the function of  simple clipboard. And other methods refering to [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html).